# Problems with iOS 6 and UIActivityIndicator in a UINavigationBar titleView

Tags: ios6, uiactivityindicatorview, uinavigationitem

been having problems with this since iOS 6.  I can't really figure out whats changed that would cause this behavior.  This used to work perfectly in 5. Now the activity indicator doesn't come up timely or at all.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
-(void)myMethod
{
    UIView *currentTitleView = [[self navigationItem] titleView];


    // Create an activity indicator and start it spinning in the nav bar
    UIActivityIndicatorView *aiview = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:aiview];
    [aiview startAnimating];

    // Start of Block code
    void (^block)(arg1, arg2) =
    ^(arg1, arg2)
    {
       block code;
       [aiview stopAnimating];
       [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:currentTitleView];
    };
// End of Block code




}
```

Comment: The issue may not be with the activity indicator method itself, but perhaps whatever calls it. Have you tried logging your AI method to make sure it's getting called reliably?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `myMethod` is being called from a background thread.  As a general rule, all interactions with UIKit elements (which includes `UIActivityIndicatorView`) should always be done on the main thread.  Try using GCD to move the UI code to the main queue (a.k.a. main thread).

```
-(void)myMethod {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIView *currentTitleView = [[self navigationItem] titleView];

        // Create an activity indicator and start it spinning in the nav bar
        UIActivityIndicatorView *aiview = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

        [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:aiview];
        [aiview startAnimating];
    });

    // Start of Block code
    void (^block)(arg1, arg2) =
    ^(arg1, arg2)
    {
       block code;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [aiview stopAnimating];
           [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:currentTitleView];
        });
    };
// End of Block code
}
```